# How to include Javascript AMD modules in a Vite project

Tags: vite, es6-modules, amd

In my project using the Vite bundler, I have the two legacy AMD libraries `azure-devops-extension-api` and `azure-devops-extension-sdk`, but Vite only supports ESM modules. The means that if I in a javascript file have:

```
import * as API from `azure-devops-extension-api`
```

The browser will output `Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined`

Would it be possible to convert the AMD modules to ESM at build time using the `rollup-plugin-amd` plugin with `build.rollupOptions`, and in that case, what should my `vite.config.ts` look like?

[EDIT 1]

With the suggestion from @Dmitry Kotov it almost work, except for vitest which gives `ReferenceError: define is not defined` that indicates vitest operates on the AMD module before conversion.

Current `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss'
import babel from 'vite-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'vite-plugin-commonjs'

export default defineConfig({
    base: '/',
    plugins: [
        react(),
        babel({
            babelConfig: {
                plugins: ['transform-amd-to-commonjs'],
            },
        }),
        commonjs(),
    ],
    server: {
        port: 8000,
    },
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [tailwindcss],
        },
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                assetFileNames: 'output.css',
            },
        },
    },
    define: {
        'process.env': {},
    },
})
```

And `vitest.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
    test: {
        reporters: ['default', 'junit'],
        coverage: {
            reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html', 'cobertura'],
            provider: 'istanbul',
        },
        environment: 'jsdom',
        globals: true,
        setupFiles: ['./src/common/test/test-setup.ts', 'dotenv/config'],
        exclude: ['**/node_modules/**', '**/temp/**'],
    },
})
```

"vite": "^4.5.1",
"vitest": "^1.0.4"

[EDIT 2]

After posting an issue on the Github of vitest I got the following answer in order to get vitest to work with AMD modules:

> By default, Vitest doesn't crawl your dependencies to pre-bundle them
> like Vite does. You can add both azure-devops-extension-sdk,
> azure-devops-extension-api to deps.optimizer.web.include, but
> currently Vitest also doesn't process those dependencies afterwards so
> commonjs plugin will not be applied which makes this useless in your
> case. However, it is possible to configure Vitest to process those
> files with both plugins by inlining them and specifying plugin options

Now, with the following `vite.config.ts` both vite and vitest processes the AMD modules correctly:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss'
import babel from 'vite-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'vite-plugin-commonjs'

/**
 * Configuration for ViteJS
 *
 * @url https://vitejs.dev/config/
 */
export default defineConfig({
    base: '/',
    plugins: [
        react(),
        babel({
            filter: /.*/,
            include: [/azure-devops-extension-api/, /azure-devops-extension-sdk/],
            babelConfig: {
                plugins: ['transform-amd-to-commonjs'],
            },
        }),
        commonjs({
            filter: (id) =>
                id.includes('azure-devops-extension-api') ||
                id.includes('azure-devops-extension-sdk'),
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        port: 8000,
    },
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [tailwindcss],
        },
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                assetFileNames: 'output.css',
            },
        },
    },
    define: {
        'process.env': {},
    },
    test: {
        reporters: ['default', 'junit'],
        coverage: {
            reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html', 'cobertura'],
            provider: 'istanbul',
        },
        environment: 'jsdom',
        globals: true,
        setupFiles: ['./src/common/test/test-setup.ts', 'dotenv/config'],
        // exclude: ['**/node_modules/**', '**/temp/**'],
        server: {
            deps: {
                inline: ['azure-devops-extension-sdk', 'azure-devops-extension-api'],
            },
        },
    },
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation is sparse and I have not been to find a useful example.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I solved the same issue.

First, convert the AMD module to a commonjs module (`vite-plugin-babel` + `babel-plugin-transform-amd-to-commonjs`), and then convert to ES6 module (`vite-plugin-commonjs`).

It works fine for me.

Here is vite plugins configuration snippet from my project

```js
import babel from "vite-plugin-babel";
import commonjs from 'vite-plugin-commonjs'

export default defineConfig({
    // ...
    plugins: [
        // ...
        babel({
            babelConfig: {
                plugins: ["transform-amd-to-commonjs"],
            },
        }),
        commonjs()
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
});
```

Comment: It almost works, however, for vitest I get errors `ReferenceError: define is not defined` that indicates that vitest operates on the AMD module before conversion.