# Duplicated files when mixing "require" and "import" with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, azure-devops, webpack-5, azure-devops-extensions

I am building [an extension](https://github.com/Sedeniono/ADO-History-Diff) for Azure DevOps using Javascript and webpack 5 to bundle all files. After having started with the `require()` syntax, I tried to move to the ESM `import` way as recommended by the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#es6-recommended). There are two dependencies that cause problems, however:

- One dependency I have is the [azure-devops-extension-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-devops-extension-sdk) package. Note that it comes bundled with two flavors, one for `require` and one for ESM. Its `package.json` contains:

  ```json
  "exports": {
    "types": "./SDK.d.ts",
    "import": "./esm/SDK.min.js",
    "require": "./SDK.min.js"
  },
  ```
- Another dependency is the [azure-devops-extension-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-devops-extension-api) package, which is published **only** with the `require` syntax.

The azure-devops-extension-api package has itself a dependency to azure-devops-extension-sdk. Its published `Common\Client.js` file contains:

```js
define(["require", "exports", "azure-devops-extension-sdk"], function (require, exports, azure_devops_extension_sdk_1) {
    "use strict";
    ...
}
```

In my own code, I now try to import both dependencies via

```js
import * as adoSDK from 'azure-devops-extension-sdk';
import * as adoAPI from 'azure-devops-extension-api';
```

Unfortunately, webpack bundles both versions of the azure-devops-extension-sdk files, i.e. `./esm/SDK.min.js` due to my import, and `./SDK.min.js` due to the dependency in `Common\Client.js`. I.e. both SDK files are included in the webpack output, and also used during runtime.
The SDK has global side effects and checks that it is loaded only once:

```js
if (global._AzureDevOpsSDKVersion) {
    console.error("The AzureDevOps SDK is already loaded. Only one version of this module can be loaded in a given document.");
}
global._AzureDevOpsSDKVersion = sdkVersion;
```

This check is triggered because both files are included.

I think it is clear to me why both versions of the SDK are bundled by webpack: The "import" version because I use `import`, and the "require" version because the API-package does not use `import`.

Of course I can simply stick to using `require` in my own code to include both dependencies, and then everything works:

```js
require(['azure-devops-extension-sdk', 'azure-devops-extension-api'], 
    function (adoSDK, adoAPI) {
        // ...
    }
);
```

However, besides this, is there any way I can use `import` and tell webpack about the problem? E.g. tell webpack to ignore the `./esm/SDK.min.js` file for my import and instead use `./SDK.min.js` always? I already tried webpack rules as outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52060231/3740047) post, but this did not work.

Comment: Hi, can you check if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068126/is-it-possible-to-use-both-require-and-import-together-with-webpack/56068668#56068668) and [this question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547662/how-can-include-both-commonjs-require-syntax-and-es-modules-import-syntax-in-the?noredirect=1&lq=1) help the issue?

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT Thanks for the links. The first linked answer basically states "use `import` as much as possible". Well, that is what I am trying and what I am asking how to do in conjunction with the azure-devops-extension-api package. The second link shows how to still mix `require` with `import`, but I would like to get rid of all `require` in my own code. It is the `require` in the package's code that gives me trouble.

Comment: I was just pointed to https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-api/issues/109 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/77151318/3740047, which describes the same problem and behavior. Still my question stands, whether I can somehow instruct specifically webpack to work around the problem.